# python wrapper; correct naming for method calling

Tags: python, webdriver, wrapper, naming

I want to wrap the selenium webdriver in my own class, that each time I will call a method from my class it will handle calling and error handling to the webdriver class. what is the correct way to do it ?

```
class myClass():
    browser = ... selenium web driver ...
    def find_element_by_xpath(self, value):
        try
            browser.find_element_by_xpath(value)
        except:
            ....
```

can myClass have the same method name ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple valid ways to handle the calling and error handling of the `webdriver` class and yours should be fine.

Yes, `myClass` can have the same method names but you need to make sure you're calling the right thing. E.g

```
myClassInstance = myClass()
myClassInstance.find_element_by_xpath('thing')
```

will call `browser.find_element_by_xpath` just fine